# Using Split function in Perl but keeping the delimiters

Tags: perl

I have a file that I am reading into a string
my split function then reads the values into the array

```
my @filearray = split(/[(' ') (\n) ([-+*=])] ([/]) ([(]) ([)]) ([;])/, $filestring);
```

however, the issue I am having is that the split is NOT keeping the delimiter. One site suggested putting the delimiters in () which would tell Perl to keep em
That doesn't work however.

Edit: I want to split on new line and spaces.  I also want to split on -,+,*,/,(,),; as well.  My idea was that the above code would work but is actually removing all the delimiters entirely.
~Thanks

Comment: That's one ugly regex, and probably overkill. Bracketing the regex to tell it to capture _does_ work, but without some sample data (and desired result) it's really hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is your pattern. First, I think you've unintentionally created a character class. Stuff in `[ ]` make a list of possible characters to match:

```
 [(' ') (\n) ([-+*=])]
```

I don't know what you are trying to match so I don't know how to fix that for you.

After that I think you are working two hard:

```
([/]) ([(]) ([)]) ([;])
```

I think you are trying to split on any of those characters but you make character classes for each character. You must escape the opening paren because it would otherwise start a subcapture. I think you want an alternation. A vertical bar, `|`, separates the possibilities:

```
/|\(|)|;
```

To capture them you can surround the whole thing with parentheses. Anything captured in parentheses will be part of the output list of `split`:

```
(/|\(|)|;)
```

This looks a bit ugly. You can use the `/x` modifier (`split /.../x, ...`) to make literal whitespace insignificant so you can spread out the pattern to make it easier to read:

```
( / | \( | ) | ; )
```

Perhaps someone can be of more help if you show some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, brackets keep delimiter but your regexp is broken. State clearly what do you want to achieve and then you may be could get a solution.

> If the PATTERN contains capturing groups, then for each separator,
>   an additional field is produced for each substring captured by a
>   group (in the order in which the groups are specified, as per
>   backreferences); if any group does not match, then it captures the
>   "undef" value instead of a substring. Also, note that any such
>   additional field is produced whenever there is a separator (that
>   is, whenever a split occurs), and such an additional field does
>   not count towards the LIMIT. Consider the following expressions
>   evaluated in list context (each returned list is provided in the
>   associated comment):
>
> ```
>             split(/-|,/, "1-10,20", 3)
>             # ('1', '10', '20')
>
>             split(/(-|,)/, "1-10,20", 3)
>             # ('1', '-', '10', ',', '20')
>
>             split(/-|(,)/, "1-10,20", 3)
>             # ('1', undef, '10', ',', '20')
>
>             split(/(-)|,/, "1-10,20", 3)
>             # ('1', '-', '10', undef, '20')
>
>             split(/(-)|(,)/, "1-10,20", 3)
>             # ('1', '-', undef, '10', undef, ',', '20')
> ```

```
$ perl 
my @filearray = split(/[(' ') (\n) ([-+*=])] ([/]) ([(]) ([)]) ([;])/, $filestring);
Invalid [] range "[-+" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[(' ') (\n) ([-+ <-- HERE *=])] ([/ at - line 1.
```