# Using Perl split function to keep (capture) some delimiters and discard others

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I am using Perl's split function to split up the contents of a file.

For example:

```
This foo file has+ a bunch of; (random) things all over "the" place
```

So let's say I want to use whitespace and the semicolons a delimiters.

So I would use something like:

```
split(/([\s+\;])/, $fooString)
```

I'm having trouble figuring out a syntax (or even if it exists) to capture the semicolon and discard the whitespace.

Comment: Adding an example input and desired output would make your question clearer.

Comment: @hEr0, given the variety of answers, it is quite clear that you need to provide input and expected output. I edited your question thinking that I was getting what you wanted, but I am no longer sure about that...

Comment: Wait wait wait, did you create another account after being told to modify your post? Because the same question has been asked like 2 hours before yours

Comment: Is this also your question? [Using Split function in Perl but keeping the delimiters \[on hold\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647834/using-split-function-in-perl-but-keeping-the-delimiters) Please don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to ask for something like

```
my @fields_and_delim = split /\s+|(;)/, $string;  # not quite right
```

but this isn't quite what it may seem. It also returns empty elements (with warnings) since when `\s+` matches then the `()` captures nothing but `$1` is still returned as asked, and it's `undef`. There are yet more spurious matches when your delimiters come together in the string.

So filter

```
my @fields_and_delim = grep { defined and /\S/ } split /(\s+|;)/, $string;
```

in which case you can normally capture the delimiter.

---

This can also be done with a regex

```
my @fields_and_delim = $string =~ /([^\s;]+|;+)/g;
```

which in this case allows more control over what and how you pick from the string.

If repeated `;` need be captured separately change `;+` to `;`

Comment: Thank you very much. you sir are a scholar and a gentleman. perfect.

Comment: FYI to the reader: In spite of my best effort I have no idea what the -1 is for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is as simple as:

```
split /\s*;\s*/, $fooString;
```

That will separate around the `;` character that may or may not have any whitespace before or after.

In your example:

```
>This foo file has+ a bunch of; (random) things all over "the" place<
```

It would split into:

```
>This foo file has+ a bunch of<
```

and:

```
>(random) things all over "the" place<
```

By the way, you need to put the result of `split` into an array; for instance:

```
my @parts = split /\s*;\s*/, $fooString;
```

Then `$parts[0]` and `$parts[1]` would have the two bits.

Answer (score 0):

I think `grep` is what you're looking for really, to filter the list for values that aren't all whitespace:

```
my @all_exc_ws = grep {!/^\s+$/} split(/([\s\;])/, $fooString);
```

Also I removed the `+` from your regex since it was inside the `[]`, which changes its meaning.